# Problems with AsyncTask class and UDP communication

Tags: android, android-asynctask, udp, udpclient

I am trying to send messages through the UDP communication of an android phone a UDP host, according to the buttons on the screen send a specific message, I have a UDP_Service class where I instantiate the datagramsocket and do the corresponding sending:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class UDP_Service {

  private int server_port;
  DatagramSocket skt;
  private InetAddress local;
  private String msge;
  private String st;
  private int msge_lenght;
  private byte[] byteMsge;
  private byte[] resp;
  private int j;

  public UDP_Service(){
    try {
      skt = new DatagramSocket();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      // st = null;
    }
  }

  public void setIP(String ip){
    try {
      local = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      //  st = null;
    }
  }

  public void setPort(int np){
    server_port = np;
  }

  public void setMsge(String msj){
    msge = msj;
    msge_lenght = msge.length();
    byteMsge = msge.getBytes();
    resp = new byte[1024];
  }

  public void Enviar(){
    try {
      skt = new DatagramSocket();
      DatagramPacket pqtEnvio = new DatagramPacket(byteMsge, msge_lenght, 
      local, server_port);
      skt.send(pqtEnvio);
      DatagramPacket pqtResp = new DatagramPacket(resp, resp.length);
      skt.receive(pqtResp);
      st = new String(pqtResp.getData(),0,pqtResp.getLength());
      //skt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // st = null;
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    skt.close();
  }

  public String getRespuesta(){
    return st;
  }

  public int getCont() {
    return j;
  }

  public void setCont(int x) {
    j = x;
  }
}
```

The method "Enviar()" I invoke it from an AsyncTask, however it only works once, I open the application from the phone and press any button and effectively the corresponding message is sent, but when I press another button no longer nothing happens. The onPostExecute () method of the AsyncTask is not running,I can not see the corresponding toast.

Here the AsyncTask

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  String msje[];
  String resp[];
  int port;
  UDP_Service UDP_Serv;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UDP_Serv = new UDP_Service();
    //UDP_A = new UDP_Async();
    msje = new String[9];
    resp = new String[8];
    }

   public void UDP_Client(String mje, int pt, String ip, int c)
   {
    //UDP_A = new UDP_Async();
    UDP_Serv.setMsge(mje);
    UDP_Serv.setPort(pt);
    UDP_Serv.setIP(ip);
    UDP_Serv.setCont(c);
    new UDP_Async().execute();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  public class UDP_Async extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Boolean > {

  private String st;
  private int j;

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...params) {
   UDP_Serv.Enviar();
   st = UDP_Serv.getRespuesta();
   j = UDP_Serv.getCont();
   //return st;
   return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   //super.onPostExecute(result);
   if (result) {
    if (!st.equals(null)) {
     resp[j] = st;
     actualizarUI(j);
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TAREA FINALIZADA!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: please show only relevant code, not whole your project.

Comment: my bad, done, add:  i got this on android monitor   `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fc21191f840`